# Association using has_many :through problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an application which has two models products and purchases.

Products contains a list of all products in my system and purchases define all the purchases made by users...

now i have a particular current_user who can view products and buy products and wen he hits buy button , he shuld b able to see all the purchases he made. i have made a association `has_many  :through` and have created a new model named purchased_products which links the purchase and products table together..

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchased_products
  has_many :purchases, :through => :purchase_products
end

class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, :through => :purchased_products
  has_many :purchased_products
end

class PurchasedProducts < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :purchases
  belongs_to :products
end
```

now I'm not getting how do i find out which user has purchased which product and show all his purchases?

Also where do i specify the code to find out all purchases of current user?

Answer (score 0):

You can access a `Product`'s `Purchase`s and vise-versa with two very simple statements like so:

```
some_product = Product.find(some_product_id_or_find_query).purchases
some_purchases = Purchase.find(some_purchase_id_or_find_query).products
```

You have not defined the relationship between the `User` and any `Purchase`, I assume this is going to be another HABTM association so you can then access them just like you can with Product->Purchases and Purchases->Product.

You should definitely search around Google for this sort of thing as ActiveRecord associations are very well documented, http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: this is my association between user and products and purchases class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :products
has_many :purchases
end

Answer (score 0):

If the a `User` has_many products and purchases, then you would reference them like, probably in you `users_controller` show action:

```
@current_user = User.find(params[:id])
@products     = @current_user.products
@purchases    = @current_user.purchases
```